# Advice on using postgresql temp_tablespace

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have been running a query that (I assume) generates a large amount of temporary information, as I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not write block 16451641 of temporary file: No space left on device
HINT:  Perhaps out of disk space?

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not write block 16451641 of temporary file: No space left on device
SQL state: 53100
Hint: Perhaps out of disk space?
```

I made a folder `tmp_tablespace` on my `G:` drive and then edited `postgresql.conf` and restarted the database.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Statement Behavior -

#search_path = '"$user",public'     # schema names
#default_tablespace = ''        # a tablespace name, '' uses the default
temp_tablespaces = 'G:/tmp_tablespace/'         # a list of tablespace names, '' uses
```

As far as I can tell, the temporary tablespace is not being used, as no files are written there (at least none that I can see when refreshing). In the Windows `Options` menu, `Show Hidden Files` is checked, and I've refreshed the folder a few times while this processing was running, as well as checking the folder size which stayed at 0.

In my SQL code, I also tried using the lines `SET temp_tablespaces('G:\tmp_tablespace');` and `temp_tablespaces('G:\tmp_tablespace');` but both lines returned error messages.

I'm using PostGreSQL 9.1 32 bit and Windows 7. Are there any other settings I should be checking? My PostGreSQL installation is on the `C:\` drive and the associated tablespace is on the `G:\` drive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the new tablespace with `CREATE TABLESPACE` and then specify the name of the tablespace in your configuration, not the name of the underlying directory.

Comment: Is it a similar command to creating a normal tablespace? I just want the temporary files there, rather than all files and if I use `CREATE TABLESPACE dbspace LOCATION '/data/dbs';` I assume it moves everything.

Comment: Why do you assume that?

Comment: From the docs, `CREATE TABLESPACE` registers a new cluster-wide tablespace. The tablespace name must be distinct from the name of any existing tablespace in the database cluster.` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtablespace.html

Comment: Nothing will move when you create a new tablespace - it will be empty until you tell postgres to put something in it. Such as by telling it to put temporary tables there.

Comment: @TomH Sorry, I'm still not clear on how to do this. So if I run `CREATE TABLESPACE dbspace LOCATION 'J:\data'` I create a tablespace, but how do I tell it to store the temporary tables there? Is it similar to `temp_tablespaces('J:\data')` ?

Comment: You set `temp_tablespaces = 'dbspace'` in your configuration, or by setting that as the default temporary tablespace for a particular database with `ALTER DATABASE`.

Answer (score 1):

After making the folder `tmp` on drive J, the approach that I took was as follows:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE dbspace_tmp LOCATION 'J:\tmp';
CREATE DATABASE dbspace_tmp tablespace dbspace_tmp;
ALTER DATABASE my_db SET temp_tablespaces = dbspace_tmp;
```

This appears to be working as it created a file in this location and it seems to be storing temporary data in there.

Comment: why you need the `create database` statement?

Comment: I think he meant to say `CREATE DATABASE my_db`